# For-loop will not end

Tags: c++, for-loop, counter

I must apologize in advance for any ambiguity, but I am just about as new to C++ as it gets. I am in an introductory-level programming course and have not actually learned real code yet, only pseudocode, and I am trying to work ahead. I am trying to create a program to calculate the number of leap days between the year 2013 and a user-input year. I am guessing that my for-loop is not ending for some reason because the program will not end, display the output, or allow any further input. I must have a logic error or simple syntax error somewhere, but cannot spot it. I get no errors when compiling. I am looking for a simple beginner answer if possible.

Thank you in advance.

```
int main()
{
int yearOfBirth, counter=0, remainder;
bool isLeapYear=false;
int totalLeapDays=0;

//Input

cout << "Enter your birth year:";
cin >> yearOfBirth;

for ((counter=yearOfBirth);(counter=2013);counter++)
{

remainder=counter%4;

if (remainder == 0)
    {
    isLeapYear = true;
    }
if (isLeapYear)
    {
    totalLeapDays ++;
    }
}

cout << "Total number of leap days: " << totalLeapDays;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `counter=2013;` theres your problem. did you forget a `<` in there?

Comment: That fixed my issue. Thank you! Now to fix the math...

Comment: Also you can remove those parentheses, they don't add anything but do inhibit readability slightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(counter=2013)
```

Middle of the for loop is the problem. One = is just assigning 2013 to counter.

Comment: Changed it to <= and it works perfectly after adding in a statement to return the isLeapYear flag back to false. Thank you for the quick response.